# Navigating Oracle Linked Servers in SQL Server through Data Grip

Tags: sql-server, jdbc, datagrip

I have an SQL Server that is setup with Linked Servers (Oracle servers, if it matters). Through SQL Server Management Studio I can query them directly with something like this:

```
SELECT TOP 100 *
FROM [linked_Server_Name]..[ORACLE_SCHEMA_NAME].[TABLE_NAME]
```

This works fine, but I'd like to do this through Data Grip (or any other 3rd party SQL IDE).

I have setup Data Grip's Data Source as SQL Server (Microsoft), and connection works great, and I can even copy-paste the working query above and it works in Data Grip.

The problem is that the application can't resolve the symbols, so the intellisense/autocomplete can't work. I also can't figure out how to browse the server objects in Data Grip, as on the Database tab under "More Schemas..." I can't locate anything that resembles server objects, linked servers, or the oracle servers/schemas.

Is there any way to locate and browser through these linked servers using Data Grip (or any other 3-rd party tool)? I'd ideally like to both browse and use autocomplete and hinting as well. Any changes to the servers are out of the question - only have the ability to alter my client.

Comment: There is no support for this, but there is an issue in the tracker: https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/DBE-3934